# sql server 2008: sp_RENAME table disappeared

Tags: sql, sql-server

I renamed the table by sp_RENAME (SQL SERVER 2008)

```
sp_RENAME 'dbname.scname.oldtblname' 'dbname.scname.newtblnam'
```

The resulting message (it was in black color - so I get it as just a warning or successful message) was something like "Caution: Changing any part of an object name could break scripts and stored procedures."

So after this command my table with 45 million records just disappeared and I don't have any backup. This was a new table.

:) Do you guys have any idea about bringing my table back?  :)

p.s. Yeah, my smile is not ":(", because when the seriousness of the problem goes up the threshold, ":(" becomes ":)".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- What does this say? 
  SSMS does not refresh Object explorer automatically so it could be there

  USE dbname
  SELECT OBJECT_ID('scname.newtblnam')
- [sp_rename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx) says

> You can change the name of an object
>   or data type in the current database
>   only. The names of most system data
>   types and system objects cannot be
>   changed.

You specified dbname so it's possible you have an object `[dbname.scname.newtblnam]` in dbo schema (or similar)

- And did you do a backup first? Best practice before any (formal) schema changes, y'know

FWIW, I've never lost a table or other object using sp_rename

Comment: Yeah, it was under schema "scname", but name was "dbname.scname.newtblnam". And I did not realize that because of hundreds of tables. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Faced that awful bug too, here is the solution:

```
--original
sp_RENAME 'dbname.scname.oldtblname', 'dbname.scname.newtblnam' 

--workaround 
sp_RENAME 'dbname.scname.[dbname.scname.newtblnam]','oldtblname'
```

name in [] is actually your TABLE name after sp_rename, to make SQL server to understand it put it in square brackets.

Answer (score 4):

I found this a little unclear, but reading the docs for [sp_rename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) reveals that

```
exec sp_rename 'udt.TenorSymbol_t_temp', 'udt.TenorSymbol_t', 'USERDATATYPE'
```

will create a type

```
udt.udt.TenorSymbol_t
```

So to create the type in the correct schema, don't specify the schema on rename

```
exec sp_rename 'udt.TenorSymbol_t_temp', 'TenorSymbol_t', 'USERDATATYPE'
```